# Show that a function is integrable (Riemann)

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $A = (a,b)$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

$A\subset \left [ -N,N \right ]$ and let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined such that $f(x) = \left \{1 \;\;  x\in A, \;\; 0\;\; x\notin A  \right \}$

Show that $f(x)$ is integrable over $\left [ -N,N \right ]$

I was thinking about showing that the upper integral and the lower are the same, But I can't manange that.

Comment: You can split the integral into three parts $[-N,a]$, $(a,b)$, and $[b,N]$ then add them together.

Comment: How would you show that the integral of $f(x) = \begin{cases} 1, & x = 0\\ 0, & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$ on $[0,1]$ exists (and is equal to $0$)?

Comment: If you are not allowed to split the integral as CyclotomicField suggests (because that result is "yet to be proven"), how you do this depends highly on what definition of Riemann integration you are using. My personal favorite for this limits by partition: for each $\epsilon$ there is a partition $P$ such that every subpartition sums to within $\epsilon$ of the limit. With that definition, you just always pick $a,b$ as partition elements, and you are golden, If you are limiting by partition norm instead, you have to show contributions from the intervals containing $a, b$ go to $0$.